# how do twilio makes browser to phone calls

Tags: protocols, twilio

what protocol does it use?what languages does it use.please explain in detail.where can I learn these?I wanted to make an app which can make a browser to phone call for lowcost

Answer (score 1):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Our client-side solution is built on top of the [WebRTC standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC). If you want to start building here's [a tutorial that walks you through building an app that places a browser to phone call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/click-to-call/php/laravel). You didn't mention a language preference but you can toggle this tutorial between PHP, Node.js, Python or Ruby.